Google Cloud Functions for Firebase: How do I render an image response in React?
I'm using Google Cloud Functions for Firebase (GCFF) to make my API calls on the backend of my simple React web app. Here's a simple one that fetches a picture from Wikipedia.
I've tried many different variations of header types, blob() calls, btoa() calls, etc. between the front-end and back-end, but I haven't been able to get a usable src URL for an img tag. At best I get a broken image icon.
Here's the simplest version of the code:
Back-end (Cloud Function for Firebase):
exports.testPhotoRender = onRequest(
    {cors: true},
    (request, response) => {
      const options = {
        method: "GET",
      };
      const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/"+
        "commons/7/77/Delete_key1.jpg";

      axios.get(url, options)
          .then((r) => {
            response.send(r.data);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            response.sendStatus(e);
          });
    });

Front-end (React/JS):
const res = await fetch(testRenderPhotoUrl); // URL for the GCFF
const blob = await res.blob();
const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
setImage(
  <>
    <img src={imageUrl}/>
  </>
);

And then that image component is rendered within the React component.

Got working code after more trial and error. I assume there are some unnecessary conversions but it works. I will comment if I simplify it further.
Back-end:
Note that r.data is now Buffer.from(r.data, "binary").toString("base64")
exports.testPhotoRender = onRequest(
    {cors: true},
    (request, response) => {
      const options = {
        method: "GET",
      };
      const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/"+
        "commons/7/77/Delete_key1.jpg";

      axios.get(url, options)
          .then((r) => {
            response.send(Buffer.from(r.data, "binary").toString("base64"));
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            response.sendStatus(e);
          });
    });

Front-end:
Using .text() instead of .blob() worked.
const text = await res.text();
const imageSrc = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+text;
setImage(
  <>
    <img src={imageSrc}/>
  </>
);

